# How to build a snap to grid feature for drag and drop puzzle pieces?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-development

I'm playing around with building a sort of Tetris/1010! style puzzle game with SpriteKit and Swift. I'd like the game to present a puzzle piece composed of several blocks to the user. The user can then drag and drop the puzzle piece onto a grid. If the user selected area on the grid has open slots, the puzzle piece will snap to the nearest slots and occupy them.

I'm unsure of how to implement the "snap puzzle piece to grid" portion of this problem. Any suggestions on how I might approach this from a high level point of view? An image below for more context.

Thanks ahead of time for any help.

[image: tiles]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have created both objects you can check for their center and compare it to the centers of the rows and match it for the closest one for example:

Assuming 100 pixels between each row you might have

center of row1 = (100, 100)

center of row2 = (100, 200)

center of row3 = (100, 300)

You can calculate the center for each row easily since you have their center points

in the touches ended function you will compare the block's center point to each one and take care of the cases:

- Get the nearest center of the 3 rows from the block's center
- Check if that center is empty if yes then snap the block by making

  block.center = row[i].center
- if no then match to the next nearest row
- if no rows are empty then you should've terminated the game

This work wherever the block was on the screen because you have full information about both objects